# why there is so many closed curves in this graph?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm studying ODE recently.

When I'm solving one question, I realized that:

(1) $ F(x,y)=-\cot(x+y)+\csc(x+y)-x-\sqrt{2}+1=0 $

(2) $ G(x,y)=\tan\frac{(x+y)}{2}-x-\tan\frac{\pi}{8}=0$

are actually the same functions.

They are all right answers for the ordinary differential equation with initial value:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=cos(x+y), y(0)=\pi/4$

When I try to plot $H(x,y)=F(x,y)-G(x,y)$, I got an excited image.

[graph of H(x,y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDWSS.png)

I just want to ask why there is so many closed curves in this graph?

More specifically, to know why it happens, which books should I read?

Thanks!

Comment: Computer cannot represent all real number exactly. When you plot $F(x,y) = G(x,y)$, you are picking up the noise from the rounding errors of $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$. ( even $F(x,y) = G(x,y)$, there is no guarantee whats returned from $F$ and $G$ has exactly the same machine representation).

Comment: See the answer I gave some time ago to a similar question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2246303