# Why am I getting $1$ instead of $e$?

Tags: limits

I'm trying to use a calculator to verify the following formula
$$
e=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + (1/n))^n.
$$

According to the calculator the value of $e$ to 9 decimal place accuracy is $2.718281828$.

When I plug in $n=1000000000$ above, I get that $1.000000001^{1000000000}\approx 2.718281827$, which is pretty close to $e$.

However, when I plug in $n=10000000000$ I get that $1.0000000001^{10000000000}\approx 2.718942354$, which is further from $e$, despite having plugged a higher natural number for $n$. Then, when I plug in much higher natural numbers for $n$, it seems be getting closer to $1$. What might I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+\frac12}$$ has better convergence, but it will also suffer from rounding errors when $n$ is too large.

Comment: There's good info here about how computers handle floating-point arithmetic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4014959 However, calculators don't always do stuff in the same way that computers do it.

Comment: @PM2Ring Why $1\over 2$? Is there a different number you could put there to get "better convergence?" (I'm curious)

Comment: @Mike Well, for $n>0$, we get $(1+\frac1n)^n < e < (1+\frac1n)^{n+1}$, and both of those expressions converge to $e$ as $n$ grows. So $n+\frac12$ is a natural choice. BTW, this is related to the (real) solutions of $x^y=y^x$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9505/207316) & the links therein for more details. For small $n$, there are certainly better choices than $n+\frac12$.

Comment: A powerful computational engine such as Wolfram Alpha actually gets things write when $n=1000000000$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1000000000%7D%29%5E%281000000000%29).

Comment: (cont) For actual computation, it's better to rearrange it to $(1+1/(n-1/2))^n$, and make $n$ a power of 2, so you can do the exponentiation by repeated squaring.

Comment: Here's a little Sage / Python [script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzyMwrSS1KTC7hSklNUyhJLS7RyLU1NLLQtOJSAIJSBVuFPA1DBW0FQ_1cTbBQWn6RQrZCZp6ChoEOUNQISEAVg0BBEdBAjWwdhdI4jVztbE1NAOHlGBc=&lang=sage) that shows the results of $(1+1/m)^{m+k}$ for $k$ in $(0, 1/2, 1)$. And [this script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzyMwrSS1KTC7hSklNUyhJLS7RyLU1NLLQtOJSAIK0_CKFbIXMPAUNQ30jHQUgoaALJDUMjbRyNaFqQKBUwVYhT8NQQRskmQtUk62pCZcsKAJaolEal6sJABMwGh8=&lang=sage) shows we can do better than $k=1/2$.

Comment: BTW, if the goal is to compute decimal digits of $e$, there are better ways, especially if you want lots of digits. Eg, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1295561/207316

Answer (score 10):

I assume this is just calculator rounding errors. For some sufficiently high $n$, your calculator won't want to think about the number
$$1.00000000000000000000000000000000000...0000000000000000000000000001$$
but will instead just round that to $1$. For your example with $n = 10\,000\,000\,000$, it looks like the calculator is still pretty happy with that number, but somewhere in the calculation of $\left(1+{1 \over n}\right)^n$ it becomes unhappy and makes rounding errors. Specifically *what* errors depends on how your calculator handles calculating powers of floats (decimal numbers).

Comment: I have given in my answer what happens precisely not with a pocket calculator but with a numerical analysis software, Matlab.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to give here the behavior of a numerical analysis software, Matlab, to which we have asked to compute $\left(1+\frac{1}{10^n}\right)^{10^n}$ for $n=1,2,\cdots 20$:

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|}
\hline
 1&  2.000000000000000\\
   2&   2.593742460100002\\
   3&   2.704813829421529\\
   4&   2.716923932235594\\
   5&   2.718145926824926\\
   6&   2.718268237192298\\
   7&   2.718280469095753\\
   8&   2.718281694132082\\
   9&   2.718281798347358\\
  10&   2.718282052011560\\
  11&   2.718282053234788\\
  12&   2.718282053357110\\
  13&   2.718523496037238\\
  14&   2.716110034086901\\
  15&   2.716110034087023\\
  16&   3.035035206549262\\
  17&   1.000000000000000\\
  18&   1.000000000000000\\
  19&   1.000000000000000\\
  20&   1.000000000000000\\
\hline
  \end{array}$$

Why this sudden change past $10^n=10^{16}$ ?

Because, with $\left(1+10^{-17}\right)^{10^{17}}$, we are below the **machine's epsilon** ( a classical expression) which is precisely

$$eps=2.220446049250313 \times 10^{-16}$$

and is defined as the smallest "floating point" number representable with Matlab.

In fact $\left(1+10^{-17}\right)^{N}$ is like $\left(1+0\right)^{N}=1$ for this software.

The fact that the results are never very good (never better than a $3 \times 10^{-8}$ approximation: recall that $e \approx 2.718281828459046...$) is another thing and should deserve a separate analysis.

Remark: for another interesting occurence of the machine's epsilon, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2246303).